# @Version not working with spring data jpa, Hibernate and Db2

Tags: spring

**Spring Data JPA** with **DB2** doesn't working. I am using `org.springframework.data.annotation.Version`; as a version annotation.

Comment: What happens if you use `@javax.persistence.Version` instead of `@org.springframework.data.annotation.Version`?

Comment: The answer is in the question. JPA doesn't care about Spring annotations. Use the JPA annotation.

Comment: Thanks Guys!! @manish JB Nizet, i posted my finding too :)